# how to run a method in csharp exactly ten times and then go to another method

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

How to run a method exactly ten times in csharp?
I'm writing a c#/xaml windows8 app, and I want to run some method for button exatcly 10 times, and when it is called 10th time, I want it to go on to another method that will execute itself.

My button in XAML leads to this method I want to use ten times, to get 10 different images every time (I still haven't figured how to get different images every time because if-else loop in this method is infinite):

```
 public void LoadImage_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

            Random rand = new Random();
            int pic = rand.Next(1,0)
            myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///img/" + pic +".jpg"));

    }
```

and after it runs for the 10th time I want to use another method on the same button

Comment: just have class level `int counter` increment it in the method and check if the `counter <= 10`

Comment: i've pasted a wrong code in line 7, it said: "int pic = rand.Next(1,0) " instead of "int pic = rand.Next(1,10);"

Comment: well this has nothing to do with your original problem "executing the code 10 times"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, this can be accomplished using a simple counter.

```
private volatile int _loadImageCount = 0;

public void LoadImage_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _loadImageCount += 1;

    if (_loadImageCount > 10)
    {
        UpdateImage();
    }
    else
    {
        UpdateRandomImage();
    }
}

private void UpdateRandomImage()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int pic = rand.Next(1,0)
    myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///img/" + pic +".jpg"));
}

private void UpdateImage()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't help because when i put 

   `myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///img/specific-pic.jpg"));`

as a specific 11th picture into `private void UpdateImage()`, running this code doesn't show random pictures, it only shows that `specific-pic.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

```
int numberOfExecutions=0;



public void LoadImage_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

            if(numberOfExecutions < 10)
            {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int pic = rand.Next(1,0);
            myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///img/" + pic +".jpg"));
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Dududu!");

             numberOfExecutions++;

    }
```

Comment: i've pasted a wrong code in line 7, it said: "int pic = rand.Next(1,0) " instead of "int pic = rand.Next(1,10);"

but it still executes infinitly

Comment: Try the change to my code, check if the tenth+ time it shows the MessageBox

Comment: i haven't managed to make it work since in Metro apps there is no MessageBox supported, but MessageDialog is, but it haven't worked for me, however d.moncada's solution worked, but thank you a lot anyway